# Android PushNotification From Json URL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, push-notification

I have a Json URL, which contains data about Latest Job Postings, I am successfully parsing the Json URL and able to display the top job postings in my ListView.

But my requirement is to create a push notification, so that whenever a new job is posted, the user should be able to get a notification on device.

I have followed this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

But I don't know how to get notifications in my case.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: do you want to give push notification even when your application is not displaying itself on screen (in-short foreground)?

Comment: yes exactly,notification from JSON URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue:**

Give push notification to user's device about the updated data even when application is in background mode.

**Solution:**

Upon **successful** insertion of new data in your database (which is going to give updated set of data to your JSON request) , just call the file which send GCM push notification to all your users.

**Reference:**

1. [GCM docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
2. [GCM push-notification using php server](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

In context of implementation presented in demo app of 2nd link,

upon successful insertion,you can call `send_message.php` file,but make sure that `$regId` and `$message` should be retrieved from your database

Answer (score 2):

You have created ActionBar Notifications for your app, but now you need to create the ability to receive notifications from a web client, instead of going to find them yourself from the URL.

To create a push notification you would need to have a constant thread (BroadcastReceiver) on the device that is waiting for the notification from the sever.

Google 'Cloud to Device Messaging' is the simplest way to do this.

This is a good link with lots of info on how to do this :

http://blog.mediarain.com/2011/03/simple-google-android-c2dm-tutorial-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

If you require these notifications to be displayed on the device even when the application is not running (which seems to be the case from what you describe), you can use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

You would need a server that would poll the Json URL for updates, and send a GCM message to all the devices where your app is installed once such an update is detected.

Your app would have to register to Google Cloud Messaging and send the Registration ID received from Google to your server.

When your app receive a GCM message, you would create a notification and when the notification is tapped, you would start the activity that loads the data from the JSON URL.

Comment: You would need a server that would poll the Json URL for updates? Could you give sample code?

Comment: I don't have sample code for that. Basically, you have to run the same code you have in your app (for parsing the JSON URL) in a server, and check if something changed compared to the last time you parsed the JSON. You should do it in a loop, every X seconds/minutes (whatever the frequency you want to notify your app users of changes in the JSON). When you detect a change, you send GCM messages to all the devices that installed the app. Read about GCM in the link I provided (or in any number of tutorials you can easily find online) to find out how.

Comment: (for parsing the JSON URL) in a server? that means should i make a Post or Get Request to Server to get a message? i'm following this tutorial url http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: there used Php server and Server URL to get messages?In my case what should i use?Could you Clarify? sample Code